# dynamic sql in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have some code like this:

```
declare
 p_vara varchar2;
 p_varb varchar2;
 p_varc varchar2;
begin

INSERT INTO MY_INSERTABLE_TABLE
SELECT a.id,b.id,c.id
FROM table_a a, table_b b, table_c c
WHERE a.id is not null
      and a.id = b.id
      and c.id = 'cat'
end;
```

Now based on the the variable to make it conditional so that only certain parts of the query get called based on the variable.

```
declare
 p_vara varchar2;
 p_varb varchar2;
 p_varc varchar2;
begin

INSERT INTO MY_INSERTABLE_TABLE
SELECT a.id, -- Show only if p_vara = 'yes'
       b.id, -- Show only if p_varb = 'yes'
       c.id  -- Show only if p_varc = 'yes'
FROM table_a a, -- Use only if p_vara = 'yes'
     table_b b, -- Use only if p_varb = 'yes'
     table_c c  -- Use only if p_varc = 'yes'
WHERE a.id is not null -- Use only if p_vara = 'yes'
      and a.id = b.id -- Use only if p_vara = 'yes' and p_varb = 'yes'
      and c.id = 'cat' -- Use only if p_varc = 'yes'
end;
```

So for example if the variables are set as this:

```
p_vara = 'yes'
p_varb = 'no'
p_varc = 'no'
```

Then the query should look like this:

```
SELECT a.id    
FROM table_a
WHERE a.id is null;
```

Comment: Sorry, this is just an example. I have changed a.id is null to a.id is not null. Should work now.

Comment: This isn't filtering of the query.  What you are looking for is dynamic SQL where the query statement itself varies based on some defined input.  As a part of your dynamic SQL you should specify a dynamic list of column you are inserting into unless your `MY_INSERTABLE_TABLE` has only one column and `p_vara`, `p_varb`, and `p_varc` are mutually exclusive, which based on your second predicate `and a.id = b.id -- Use only if p_vara = 'yes' and p_varb = 'yes'` isn't true

Comment: Do you really only have 3 variables and a total of 8 possible combinations?  At that point, it may be simpler to just code 8 separate static SQL statements.  Your full query, for example, is joining 3 tables but only has 1 join condition so it's going to create a Cartesian product.  If `p_vara = 'yes' and p_varc = 'yes'`, it would create a Cartesian product between `table_a` and `table_c`.  It is unlikely that would be what you want.

Comment: No this is just a simple bare bones example. I have about 25 variables and a long SQL query spanning over 100 lines

Answer (score 2):

As written, your requirements do not appear to be complete.  If all three variables are `yes`, for example, your full statement would have three table joins but only one join condition so you'd generate a Cartesian product with `table_c`.  If `p_vara = 'yes' and p_varc = 'yes'`, you'd have two tables joined with no join condition so you'd again have a Cartesian product.  It seems unlikely to me that you really want to generate a Cartesian product.

In general, you can build a SQL statement in a string variable and then pass that to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.  If you have 25 boolean variables, that implies that your code could generate a total of 33.55 million distinct SQL statements.  Just verifying that none of those paths generate a statement with syntax errors would be non-trivial.  Combined with the fact that resorting to dynamic SQL generally makes code harder to read, maintain, and support in addition to creating opportunities for performance and security issues, I would tend to push back on any design that contemplates something as complex as what you are describing.

That said, you could do something like this (I'm not building the `WHERE` clause out completely but I trust you get the jist)

```
declare
  l_vara boolean;
  l_varb boolean;
  l_varc boolean;

  l_sql_stmt varchar(4000);
begin
  l_sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO my_insertable_table( col1, col2, col3 ) ';
  l_sql_stmt := l_sql_stmt || ' SELECT ' ||
                (case when l_vara then ' a.id, ' else ' null, ' end) ||
                (case when l_varb then ' b.id, ' else ' null, ' end) ||
                (case when l_varc then ' c.id, ' else ' null, ' end);
  l_sql_stmt := rtrim( l_sql_stmt, ',' ); -- remove the extra trailing comma
  l_sql_stmt := l_sql_stmt || ' FROM ';

  if( l_vara )
  then
    l_sql_stmt := l_sql_stmt || ' table_a a, ';
  end if;
  if( l_varb )
  then
    l_sql_stmt := l_sql_stmt || ' table_b b, ';
  end if;
  if( l_varc )
  then
    l_sql_stmt := l_sql_stmt || ' table_c c, ';
  end if;

  -- again remove the extra trailing comma
  l_sql_stmt := rtrim( l_sql_stmt, ',' ); 

  <<build out the WHERE clause similarly>>

  -- Log the SQL statement so you can debug it when it fails
  insert into some_log_table( sql_stmt ) values( l_sql_stmt );

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
end;
```